# Modal PopUp with Symfony

Tags: symfony

I need to use a Modal PopUp box to use as a filter for my table. What is the right/common/basic way to approach this in Symfony environment?

an example; http://hypertrends.com/net/files/2010/04/modal.png

Answer (score 0):

JQuery UI Dialog is the easiest:

[Jquery UI Modal Form](http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/dialog/modal-form.html)